# How to get direction vector of Oculs Go controller in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

Does anyone know how to get the Oculus Go controller orientation vector in A-Frame?

I want to get the orientation of Oculus Go's controller and use it in the game. I understand that the "direction" property of the raycaster component used by laser-controls has that value, and tried the following code.

```
<a-scene>
  <!-- laser-controls for Oculus Go controller -->
  <a-entity id="ctl" laser-controls></a-entity>
  <!-- a-text for debug -->
  <a-text id="txt" value="" position="0 2 -2" align="center"></a-text>
</a-scene>

<script>
  const ctl = document.getElementById("ctl");
  const txt = document.getElementById("txt");
  ctl.addEventListener("triggerdown", (evt) => {
    const ray = ctl.getAttribute("raycaster");
    txt.setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify(ray.direction));
  });
</script>
```

But the value was always {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": -1} (the default value).
Please advise me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get a point in the controller's local space.
2. Convert it to world space.
3. Subtract the vectors of the point and the controller position.

   ```
   var point = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
   controllerEl.object3D.localToWorld(point);
   var worldDirection = point.sub(controllerEl.object3D.position);
   ```

`worldDirection` is a vector from the controller facing out straight from the controller, in world space.

Comment: I succeeded in getting the data I was looking for. Thank you very much for providing very valuable ideas!